# Problem burning bootloader on ATmega328P using internal clock

Tags: bootloader

I'm trying to burn the arduino bootloader onto my ATmega328P so it uses the internal clock. I followed the tutorial in this [page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard) but I'm getting this error.

```
avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Dec 16 2016 at 13:33:19
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM5
     Using Programmer              : stk500v1
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
     AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PC2
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : STK500
     Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
     Hardware Version: 2
     Firmware Version: 1.18
     Topcard         : Unknown
     Vtarget         : 0.0 V
     Varef           : 0.0 V
     Oscillator      : Off
     SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Error while burning bootloader.
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I tried placing a cap from reset to ground but it doesn't wort either.
Any idea on what might be wrong with my procedure?

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

- I followed the procedure described at the bottom of the page linked (Minimal Circuit (Eliminating the External Clock)).
- I used the bootloader in "breadboard-1-6-x.zip"
- I am using the Arduino IDE v1.8.1

Comment: It isn't clear from question+webpage what your procedure is, or what you want to do.  What  “internal clock” do you mean?  The built-in 8 MHz RC oscillator ?  If so, please edit question to say so.  Also edit question to include a schematic of how you have things hooked up.  Do you have a [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) to program the  ATmega328P system, or what?

Comment: I followed precisely the instructions listed on the link I provided. And yes it is the internal 8MHz RC oscillator

Comment: You could edit the question and say what your programmer is, what fuse settings, which bootloader.  Or just let people guess.

Comment: I though providing a link of the tutorial which answers all of your questions was enough, but I'll edit it out.

Comment: The link describes several different procedures, and I think the details of what all was done aren't clear

Comment: Ok, i'll edit it.

Comment: Step 5 of the "Minimal Circuit (Eliminating the External Clock)" says, "Once you've done this, you can burn the bootloader and upload programs onto your ATmega328 as described above."  Which of the two methods shown did you use?  **What  what what programmer are you using?**

Comment: I'm using Arduino as ISP

Comment: Please run [my chip detector sketch](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) and report the results (copy/paste).

Answer (score 1):

If your ATMEGA328P has already been used with a crystal or already has a bootloader on it, then the fuses will be set to expect a crystal oscillator. In this case, you must initially have a crystal & the associated 2 capacitors connected. Once you have succeeded in burning the bootloader (this process also sets the fuses) you can dispense with the crystal.

Comment: can I connect the ATmega Cristal pins to the arduino board?

Comment: According to this, it should be possible to share a crystal (or resonator in the case of most newer Arduino boards) : https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=78584.0

Comment: I tryed connecting to the board oscillator. Now it gives me this error:

Comment: avrdude: Device signature = 0x00ffff
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F
         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

Comment: Also the device signature keeps changing every time I try to burn the bootloader. Does this mean the ATmega is broken?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in 6v6gt's answer, if the ATmega328 has been set to use a crystal, thereafter a crystal (or an external oscillator) are required for programming, until the fuses have been set to use the internal RC oscillator.  Here are a few thoughts, unfortunately somewhat scattered, on the matter.

If you have a parallel programmer (that delivers high voltage to the Reset pin and uses 8-bit parallel data signalling) you can use it to reset the fuses, since with that programming mode the clock is irrelevant.

Also, [USBasp programmers](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) interact with Avrdude to generate a programming clock of some specified frequency,   100kHz by default, 8kHz with the “Slow Clock” jumper installed.  Also see § “Set the clock in software” within [USBasp ICSP programmer quickstart guide](http://www.freetronics.com.au/pages/usbasp-icsp-programmer-quickstart-guide) at freetronics.com.au.  Unlike the Avrdude man page, that reference says the default programming frequency is 375kHz and says “Avrdude’s -B option allows you to set the programming clock speed from software”, while the man page says -B specifies bit clock period (in microseconds) for the JTAG interface or the ISP clock of the JTAG ICE only.  Anyhow, a USBasp can reprogram fuses away from the crystal setting if a crystal or external oscillator is used, without depending on serial port data rates.  I don't know for certain whether it will work without a crystal or oscillator.

Note, rather than “sharing” a crystal via wires from one board to another – a practice that will broadcast lots of RF noise and might not get the signal across anyway – you could instead write a program on one Arduino to toggle a pin at high frequency, and use that output as an external oscillator to drive one of the crystal pins on another chip.  For example, the program below *should* generate a 2.67 MHz square wave on pin PB0 of an Uno or a Nano.

```
void setup() {
  cli();    // Avoid timer interrupts
  pinMode (8, OUTPUT); // PB0 is pin 8 on Uno / Nano
  while (1) PINB = 1;
}
void loop() {}
```

In the ATmega328 data sheet, see §14.3.1, Alternate Functions of Port B, and Table 14-3, which lists PB7 as XTAL2 (Chip Clock Oscillator pin 2), and PB6 as XTAL1 (Chip Clock Oscillator pin 1 or External clock input), indicating external oscillator attaches to the PB6 pin.

Comment: I would `cli()` before the `while`, otherwise the timer interrupt would make long glitches.

Comment: After that, how I have to connect it. The pin PB0 of the "clock generator" board to XTAL1 or XTAL2?

Comment: @jagjordi, see last paragraph of edit

Comment: I did what you said (configured the UNO to output the clock, connect pin 8 to XTAL1 (PB6) but I still get the same error. Device signature keeps changing every time I try to burn the bootloader. Any ideas?